Limit of sum involving product of integrals
$$L = \lim_{n \to ∞}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2022x+2023}dx)(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2023x+2022}dx)}$$
I was not able to even start the problem, solve the first integral, or have an idea for solving the product.
My work using Sandwich theorem ...
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{4045}dx\le \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2022x+2023}dx\le \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2023}dx$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{4045}dx\le \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2023x+2022}dx\le \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2022}dx$$
Let,
$$I(k) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2023x+2022}dx$$
$$J(k) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^k}{2022x+2023}dx$$
so,
$$4090506(k+1)^2\le \frac{1}{I(k)J(k)}\le 16200625(k+1)^2$$
Applying sum on both sides and taking the limit
$$1363502\le L\le 5400208+1/3$$
but as RHS is not equal to LHS I can not apply the Sandwich theorem here.

what is the expected answer?

I have no idea i just have a problem but using desmos answer seems to be around 4.8 * 10^6

The integrals
$$
I_k(a, b) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{a x + b} \, dx 
$$
satisfy
$$ \tag{*}
 \frac{1}{(a+b)(k+1)} \le I_k(a, b) \le \frac{1}{(a+b) k}
$$
for all real numbers $a, b > 0$ and all integers $k \ge 1$. This follows from integrating the inequalities
$$
 \frac{x^k}{a+b} \le \frac{x^k}{ax+b} \le \frac{x^{k-1}}{a+b}
$$
for $0 \le x \le 1$, which are straightforward to verify.
Using $(*)$ we get
$$
 (a+b)^2 \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{I_k(a, b) I_k(b, a)} \le (a+b)^2 \sum_{k=1}^n (k+1)^2
$$
and therefore
$$
 \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^3 }\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{I_k(a, b) I_k(b, a)} = \frac{(a+b)^2}{3} \, .
$$

It looks easy now, but it took me a while to find this proof. As one can see in the edit history, the first version of this answer was more complicated (and my first draft even more so :)
